# WebStorm. How to make IDE compile less files from src/less/... to dist/css/...?

Tags: webstorm

By default the .less files are compiled into the same directory.

But I want IDE compile to .less only from src/less/ and save .css to dist/css/ folder.

[image]

How can I do that?

Maybe I can mark folders as Sources and Destination? And then use FileDirRelativeToSourcepath?

UPDATE.

In older versions there was a "Mark as Sources".

[image]

In current version there is no this mark.
[image]

Why current version haven't this mark?

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Scope" settings?

Comment: I added local scope. But FileDirRelativeToSourcePath macros still is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To have only files from `src/less/` watched for changes, please create a custom scope in `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes` with only files from `src/less/` included, and set this scope to your file watcher
2. To save output to a different folder, you need to modify `'Output paths to refresh'` option (and, optionally, Arguments field - if you don't like creating output from stdout).

With stdout:

```
Arguments: --no-color $FileName$
Working dir: $FileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/dist/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Create output from stdout: checked
```

Without stdout:

```
Arguments: --no-color $FileName$ $ProjectFileDir$/dist/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
    Working dir: $FileDir$
    Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/dist/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

    Create output from stdout: unchecked
```

Screenshot with settings:
[image]